# SSL Android App Encryption

Tags: android, windows, ssl, encryption, service

I am hoping this is a simple yes or no answer.  I have search and there is never a clear answer, so I am hoping to gain this knowledge.

I have a web service running under https.  The server has a SSL installed for the main url that the service runs under.

I have created a tablet Android app and a desktop Windows app that both talk to the web service.  Since the web service is https, is all the data that passes between both apps and the web service encrypted?  If so, is the username/password that gets passed initially to authenticate with the web service?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL and HTTPS only encrypts the data while it transits from the client to the server. once it comes to rest on your client or server it is unencrypted.

As for the username and password it depends on what type of Authentication you are using. if you are using Basic Auth, then yes the credentials are encrypted while in transit, but you can look around and see why HTTP Basic auth isnt a good idea for other reasons.

Comment: So just to clarify, in this workflow:  client-->server-->client, both passes are encrypted?  In otherwords, Android app passes data to web service, web service responds with data back to the client.  All of that is encrypted?  Is it the same for a windows application passing data to the web service, then the web service responding back to the windows application?  All of that is encrypted?  Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes the transmission of data from the windows or android client to the server and vice versa are encrypted using SSL.